# I am using phantomjsdriver with selenium. I wanted to generate pdf of the rendered page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using phantomjsdriver with selenium. I wanted to generate pdf of the rendered page.

With phantomJS and java script (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) I am able to do this.

But I am unable to perform same using phantomjsdriver.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using Java or some other language? Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
PhantomJSDriver phantom = (PhantomJSDriver) driver;
// This line will server the purpose and will execute the required java script.
phantom.executePhantomJS(yourJavaScript,Object args);
```